# How can I force all buttons to be on the same line?

Tags: jquery, button, jquery-mobile, controls

I have a simple jquery mobile page that has 3 buttons in a controlgroup. I want them to appear on one line instead of wrapping to next line. I have played with the css, especially font-size, so that it looks fine without being too small, but I cannot get it to resize/shrink so that it fits on one line. Here is how it looks on an Galazy 3 vertically:

[image]

and horizontally:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div id="w_home" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <a href="" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext" id="prev"></a>
    <a href="" data-role="button" id="today"></a>
    <a href="" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true" id="next"></a>
</div>
```

The text in `#today` is set dynamically using date.js.

Also, a nit-pick, why is the `#today` button a pixel shorter in height than the other two?

P.S. Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rados/Ee9nq/3/) but it doesn't work without date.js

Comment: Can you show us your CSS rules? Can you provide a jsFiddle example?

Comment: I used the theme roller to create the css. Are you interested in the entire css or just the rules I changed? I tried to fiddle my code but realized that the date.js is only downloadable and without it nothing will work.